# Trouble with layout in android (ellipsized text between two buttons)

Tags: android, android-layout

Trying to make toolbar with two buttons on both sides and header between. Header should be ellisized when text is too long, like this:

```
[Button] Some quite long header te... [Button]
```

I've tried several solutions, but none help. My last try was something like this:

```
<TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:background="#444"
             android:stretchColumns="1">
    <TableRow android:background="#777" android:minHeight="60dp">
        <Button android:text="Left"/>
        <TextView android:text="Center this very long text and ellisize"
                  android:background="#f00"
                  android:lines="1"
                  android:ellipsize="end"
                  android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                  android:gravity="center"
                />
        <Button android:text="Right"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

But right button still goes away from screen...

**UPDATE:**
The solution is:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="64dip">
    <Button android:id="@+id/btnLeft"
            android:text="Left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/btnRight"
            android:text="Right"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView android:text="Center this very long text and ellisize"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:background="#f00"
              android:lines="1"
              android:ellipsize="end"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:scrollHorizontally="true"
              android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btnRight"
              android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnLeft"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**UPDATE 2:** And the second solution using TableLayout:

```
<TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:background="#444"
             android:stretchColumns="1"
             android:shrinkColumns="1">
    <TableRow android:background="#777" android:minHeight="60dp">
        <Button android:text="Left"/>
        <TextView android:text="Center this very long text and ellisize"
                  android:background="#f00"
                  android:lines="1"
                  android:ellipsize="end"
                  android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                  android:gravity="center"
                />
        <Button android:text="Right"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a relative layout instead of a table layout. If you set up the two buttons to be aligned left and right respectively, you can set the text field to span between the two buttons with the   `layout_alignRight` and `layout_alignLeft` properties. You can look at the example code for the RelativeLayout given on the android development website.

Comment: I've used some bit different properties, but you've pointed me right way. The final working code is:
`
android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btnRight"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnLeft"
`

Comment: Your table was fine, but you would need to set column index 1 to shrinkable in your XML.  Right now, you're allowing it to stretch as much as it needs.

Comment: Great, thank you, this approach also works perfectly! Updated question with both of solutions

Answer (score 0):

While the RelaviveLayout should work, another option is to add a LinearLayout set to Horizontal.  Set the three widgets to layout_width:"fill_parent" and give the TextView and both Buttons a weight (1 for each if you want them to equally take up three parts of the screen).

Not at a computer to test it right now, but should theoretically work.